# vue-katex not rendering math and displaying large black box

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, katex

I've just tried to use the vue-katex module https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-katex.

I set up a simple example using vue-cli

```
$ vue init webpack-simple my-project
```

And then I added the `vue-katex` package, added the few lines of code to put some KaTeX mathematical stuff on the page and started my dev server. **However, the mathematical notation is not displaying properly, and I'm getting a big black box displayed on my page.**

Here's the relevant part of my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "vue": "^2.5.11",
  "vue-katex": "^0.1.2"
},
"browserslist": [
  "> 1%",
  "last 2 versions",
  "not ie <= 8"
],
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
  "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
  "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
  "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
  "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
  "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
  "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
  "vue-loader": "^13.0.5",
  "vue-template-compiler": "^2.4.4",
  "webpack": "^3.6.0",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1"
}
```

Here's my app code (I've tried to take the code directly from the vue-katex npm page above):

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div v-katex:display="'\\frac{a_i}{1+x}'"></div>
    <img src="./assets/logo.png">
    ...
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueKatex from 'vue-katex';

Vue.use(VueKatex);

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And a screenshot of the result:

[image]

You can see the math doesn't render and I get this weird big black box. I've included the dev tools inspection to try to make it easier to diagnose.

I've tried to keep everything as simple as possible - if anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong, I'd really appreciate it!

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One step is missing from the vue-katex docs. If you go to the parent project, https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX you'll find that in their walk through they include a link to an external css file. You'll need to include this too:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.9.0-alpha2/katex.min.css" integrity="sha384-exe4Ak6B0EoJI0ogGxjJ8rn+RN3ftPnEQrGwX59KTCl5ybGzvHGKjhPKk/KC3abb" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: This solves the problem perfectly, I'm not sure why the npm page for `vue-katex` didn't mention this - thanks so much @Djave!